# Directive to disable element scrolling behavior and scroll page instead

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, scroll

What I'm trying to do is create a directive that when placed on an element (for example a select dropdown) disables the mouse wheel scroll for that element and instead scrolls the page. I've managed to find two approaches to this but neither is complete.

This does not allow scrolling of page while the focus is on the element (it disables all scrolling)

```
over.directive('disableSelectScroll', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element, attributes) {
            element.on('mousewheel', function (e) {
                return false;
            })
        }
    }
});
```

And this works for firefox and chrome, but does nothing for IE (11)

```
over.directive('disableSelectScroll', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element, attributes) {
            ['touchstart', 'touchmove', 'touchend', 'keydown', 'wheel', 'mousewheel', 'DomMouseScroll', 'MozMousePixelScroll'].forEach(function (eventName) {
                element.unbind(eventName);
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Do I have to redefine the scrolling behavior for when the element receives the mousewheel event or somehow link to the page scroll behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a partial work-around for this issue. Scrolling inside an element in my use case only happens when that element is focused. Remove the focus from the element and the mousewheel event should propagate upwards. The following code provided satisfactory results:

```
over.directive('disableSelectScroll', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element, attributes) {
            element.on('mousewheel', function () {
                element.blur();
            });
        }
    }
});
```

The downside to this solution is the dropdown closes when scrolling.